# Calling a function of another class from another class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am working on a project where there are two **player** objects and one **game** object.

The two player objects need to access the game object's function **display()**, but i have no idea how this could be done.

Below is a snippet highlighting the core issue:

```
class Game 
{
public:
    Game() {}
    display() {...}
    ...
};

class Player 
{
public:
    Player() {}
    void input()
    {
        ...
        // display();
        ...
    }
};
```

Please suggest a way to solve this problem. if you find fundamental issue with this design pattern, feel free to correct that!

Comment: I would question your design, especially where you have the object instances being global variables. I would suggest not having the `Game` or `Player` objects being global variables, but instead pass the `Game` object (as a reference or as a pointer) to the `Player` constructor, and have each `Player` object store this reference or pointer and use that one. Then it's easy for the `Player` objects, no matter how many there are, to call the `Game::display` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Game and Player objects werent global in my original code, but when i made the example, i made them global. But I like your idea. Ill try to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

```
void input()
{
    game.Display();
}
```

but probably, you need to pass a `Player` object to it. Thus, change it this way:

```
class Player; // FORWARD declaration
class Game 
{
public:
    Game() {}
    void display(Player& player); // Implement elsewhere not here.

    // Another way
    void display(Player* player = NULL); // Implement elsewhere not here.
    ...
};
...
 void input()
    {
        game.Display(*this);
           game.Display(this); // another way
    }
```

Comment: True that, but I gave solution against the problem in hand. May be this comment is for OP, not for me!

Comment: Thank you! But the display function has to be used by game object also, that will mean I would have to overload the exact same function?

Comment: That depends what you want to do in `display` function, and what with the `Player` object. You can change `display` to take `Player*`, and keep `NULL` as default.